# Adequate index type for a unique id

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search, database-optimization

The situation I am having is the following. I have a transactions database table. I have both an incremental id for each transaction as well as a unique ID to use for front-end purposes. An example ID would be:

**f8e3df-6af0a9-3e1d54-c2dbed86**

As you can see it uses hex values and it's divided in a 6-6-6-8 characters, making a total of 29 characters including the dashes.

For some queries I need to do the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE uuid='f8e3df-6af0a9-3e1d54-c2dbed86';
```

I have around 17,000 entries in the database and it weighs about 209 MB. When I do a query like this I profile it with phpmyadmin and the execution takes several seconds. An example of this:

[image]

As you can see it's literally a SELECT with one WHERE condition and no JOINS or other processing whatsoever.

Normally I would think this could be an index issue, but the field has the following specs:

- Type: **VARCHAR(60)**
- Index: **FULLTEXT**

I am using the basic DigitalOcean Managed MySQL with 1GB of RAM and 1 vCPU. I am considering upgrading the server, but I don't think this particular case should cause such a slow query.

Am I using the wrong type of index for this field or is this a memory problem?

Would there be a difference if I lower the type to VARCHAR(29)?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There could be a missing index or inconsistent collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FULLTEXT indexes are only employed if you use the `MATCH()...AGAINST()` predicate. You should read the documentation on how to use FULLTEXT indexes and searches: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

This is true regardless of the size of the table or the definition of your VARCHAR column. It doesn't matter if you change to VARCHAR(29).

For a comparison using `=`, you need to define an index as the default type, which is BTREE for InnoDB tables. You don't have to specify BTREE as the type of index, because it's the default.

Comment: So, if I switch to INDEX there should be a huge performance boost? What if I use LIKE for searches? Won't the FULLTEXT index be necessary there or it's only used for the MATCH()...AGAINST()?

Comment: I encourage you to try it and test the difference.

Comment: Quick follow up I still haven't done the change because there's currently a lot of movement for the next few days and I am being cautious. I have one additional question, is there a problem to keep both indexes? In case I require MATCH AGAINST later on? Like add another index on the same column?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple indexes on the same column(s).

Comment: I would recommend testing on a separate database instance than your production instance.